# Bounce effect with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, effects

Let's say I have *dice*, that are made out of sprites, and I use .click() to activate the dice to select a random number.

I have that completed, but I would like to have some kinda effect to the dice, Ive seen a lot of applications that has that bounce effect with objects and I would to love to know how to use it.

[Heres what I made](http://jsbin.com/adipo3/edit).

Any help?

Comment: But dice don't bounce? They roll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) with [easing](http://james.padolsey.com/demos/jquery/easing/).